# Can I modify function body dynamically in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I 'am creating an application in which, when user changes address then according to that address datepicker logic will change. To do so, I've first created a function which works by default. But once a user changes his delivery location than that default function's body should be changed with that one which I pass in Ajax response. What I've done is :

When page loads my function looks like:

```
var cal_logic = function(cd){
        this.setOptions({
            minDate: '<?php echo $nextday; ?>',
            defaultDate: '<?php echo $nextday; ?>',
            startDate: '<?php echo $nextday; ?>',
            maxDate: '<?php echo $nextmaxday; ?>',
        });
};
```

In my datepicker i use it like :

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    onShow : cal_logic,
});
```

Now when user changes his location using my auto-complete functionality I want to do like given below :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'index.php?route=product/product/checkAvailability',
    type : 'post',
    data : $('.delivery-data input[type=\'hidden\'],input[name=\'product_id\']'),
    beforeSend:function(){
        $('#button-cart').button('loading');
    },
    complete : function(){
        $('#button-cart').button('reset');
    },
    success : function(response){
        cal_logic = function(cd){
            this.setOptions({
                datesDescription : response['description'],
                //other changes
            });
        };
    },
});
```

Can I do like this or not? If any other suggestion or solution than please guide me.

Comment: @DanielStackenland Yes, I tried it, but it is not working. Is there any trick or way to do so?

Comment: I think it should work, just split the task into smaller pieces and you will probably find the bug

Comment: @DanielStackenland I'm trying to check but not getting success :(

Comment: Sure look at this simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/y0d89t4q/

Comment: @DanielStackenland It works, but not in my case :(